# Saving one entity with another entity in core-data swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities on core-data one is user list and another one is data list. under every user in the user list, their own data list should be saved. How can i achieve this? I tried some code, but nothing helps me.

```
guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity =
            NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "DataList",
                                       in: managedContext)!

        let data = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                   insertInto: managedContext)

        // setting fields
        data.setValue(self.txtTitle.text!, forKeyPath: "title")
        data.setValue(self.txtShortNote.text!, forKeyPath: "short_note")
        data.setValue(self.txtDescription.text!, forKeyPath: "data_description")

        // setting image
        let imageData = self.imgDocument.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.01)
        let base64Str = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

        data.setValue(base64Str, forKeyPath: "image")

        // setting date
        let currentDate = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)

        data.setValue(dateString, forKeyPath: "date")

        // save
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            arrDataList.append(data)

            SharedManager.showToast(message: "Data Added Successfully", viewController: self)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
```

This is how im saving Data into Data list.

As Im new to core-data please help me to solve this. Any sample codes would be more appreciated.
Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You have to add a relationship. The sample code in the block comment describes how to create instances of both entities –  by the way using a much better code syntax and more descriptive entity and attribute names – and assign one instance to a relationship of another. And it's highly recommended to save dates as `Date` rather than as `String`.

Comment: @vadian, Can u share some code to add relationship...?

Comment: No code, you have to add the relationship in the data model. And as I said a reasonable code is inside the block comment you've just removed.

Comment: [Here is one article](https://hackernoon.com/core-data-relationships-d813ed66ba8c) dealing with relationships in Core Data, I am sure there are many many more

Comment: @vadian yup, i already added relationship. will try with the code commented.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, i've referred the same link. the problem is the user will register and login in one viewcontroller and after login the data will be added any time in another viewcontroller.